# Reorder objects in a list based on an existing pattern in R

Tags: r, list, date, object

I have got a list of data frames, and I assigned them names based on the date in year.month format. However, in the list itself, the data frame objects are stored in the wrong order.

For example like this:

```
 [1] "2004.Apr" "2004.Aug" "2004.Dec" "2004.Feb" "2004.Jul" "2004.Jun" 
"2004.Mar" "2004.May" "2004.Nov" "2004.Oct" "2004.Jan"
```

So I want to reorder the objects within the list into the pattern illustrated below, i.e. from Jan to Dec. Is there a way of doing it without having to use a loop?

```
 [1] "2004.Jan" "2004.Feb" "2004.Mar" "2004.Apr" "2004.May" "2004.Jun" 
"2004.Jul" "2004.Aug" "2004.Sep" "2004.Oct" "2004.Nov" "2004.Dec"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can factor the list names and set levels, but I assume you have many different lists with year and month combinations. You can use the built in constant month.abb to get the corresponding index, see below:

```
# sample list
byMonthList <- list()[rep(1,11)]
names(byMonthList) <- c("2004.Apr", "2004.Aug", "2004.Dec", "2004.Feb", "2004.Jul", "2004.Jun", "2004.Mar", "2004.May", "2004.Nov", "2004.Oct", "2004.Jan")

# split month name from year.month names using strsplit 
# extract month name using sapply
ls_month <- sapply(strsplit(names(byMonthList), split="\\."), function(x) x[2])
ls_month
# [1] "Apr" "Aug" "Dec" "Feb" "Jul" "Jun" "Mar" "May" "Nov" "Oct" "Jan"

# use match and built in constant month.abb to get numeric value of months
ls_month_num <- match(ls_month, month.abb)
ls_month_num
# [1]  4  8 12  2  7  6  3  5 11 10  1

# Use ls_month_num to reorder your list
byMonthList[names(byMonthList)[order(ls_month_num)]]
# Or
byMonthList[names(byMonthList)[order(match(sapply(strsplit(names(byMonthList), split="\\."), function(x) x[2]), month.abb))]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The zoo package has the `as.yearmon`function that returns a 'yearmon'-classed value which is actually numeric and so can be used as an index:

```
 inp[ order(zoo::as.yearmon(inp, format="%Y.%b"))]

 [1] "2004.Jan" "2004.Feb" "2004.Mar" "2004.Apr" "2004.May" "2004.Jun" "2004.Jul"
 [8] "2004.Aug" "2004.Oct" "2004.Nov" "2004.Dec"
```

Data input:

```
inp <- scan(text='"2004.Apr" "2004.Aug" "2004.Dec" "2004.Feb" "2004.Jul" "2004.Jun" "2004.Mar" "2004.May" "2004.Nov" "2004.Oct" "2004.Jan"', what="")
```

Answer (score 0):

They get rearranged that way because the names are being stored as a character vector. If you do an as.factor(name_vector, levels=name_vector), then they'll stay in the right order.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The as.factor function doesn't have an date ordering capability.